# unable to set values with a temp pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, red-black-tree

This is the function I have in my file.

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* prev = nullptr; 
    Node* leftChild = nullptr;
    Node* rightChild = nullptr;
    char color;
};
void in(Node* &root, const int x){
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = x;
    Node* ptr = root;
    Node* setPrev = nullptr;
    while(ptr != nullptr){
        cout << "Did not skip" << endl;
        setPrev = ptr; 
        if(x < ptr->data)
            ptr = ptr->leftChild;
        else
            ptr = ptr->rightChild; 
    }

    ptr = newNode;
    ptr->prev = setPrev; 
    (ptr->prev == nullptr) ? ptr->color = 'B': ptr->color ='R';

    if(ptr->prev != nullptr)
        rotationHub(root);
}
```

I have reduced the # of code, so rotationHub function will not be posted along.

This is the main()

```
int main(){
  Node* root = nullptr;
  in(root, 10);
  cout << "added" << endl;
  cout << root->data << Lendl;
  return 0;
}
```

well the problem is, I have successfully added the value 10 "in the function". However, if I print it from main. I will have Segmentation fault11: which is the root->data is nullptr;

Well, if my void in function does not have &root then it makes sense that the root is not being modify even though I have set Node* ptr = root in the in function.

So in my case I have no idea why I am not able to change the root to 10.

Comment: What do you mean "print it from main"? Can you include the code that creates the issue?

Comment: `Node* ptr = root;` you make a *copy* of the pointer `root`. Any assignments to `ptr` will be lost when the life-time of `ptr`ends. You never set `root` itself, it will stay a null pointer.

Comment: I simply have a line of code in main like this cout << root->data << end;

Comment: It's really annoying when you're talking about errors in code you don't post. Please, *always* include the code that creates the problem. It's worth editing that into the question so if we run it, we can reproduce the issue and verify that we have fixed it with any solution we're trying.

Comment: Also, since `ptr` is a value, then the assignment after the loop will not add the node to the tree, it will simply overwrite the current value of `ptr`. The loop will simply not matter.

Comment: I prefer to write functions like this where the new root is the return value, as in `root = in(...)` so that there's no messing around with references to pointers.

Comment: since I am adding one value, and the root is nullptr, it will not run the while loop. I am expecting it to run everything after the while loop which is ptr= newNode;@some

Comment: Remember, any modifications to local variables are *gone* when that function goes out of scope.

Comment: @JeffreyStewart I know. But even if the loop executes, the assignment `ptr = newNode` will ignore the loop and just overwrite the value in `ptr`.

Comment: Hint: `root = ptr`.

Comment: @tadman is there another way beside root = in(...)? well I did it with recursion and I have no problem with it. However, I will have another function to do other stuffs which is quite annoying.

Comment: You're really not using C++ properly here. You *should* have a `struct` or `class` with member functions that manipulate your tree, meaning you don't need to do as much procedural heavy lifting. `root` should be a property of your tree struct/class, and the nodes themselves can be added in as necessary. What you have here is a "fancy C" version of the usual red-black tree implementation.

Comment: @tadman root = ptr works. But I am a little bit confused why it works. I pass in root with &. and ptr should inherit everything of root and can modify anything. now I am setting the root to ptr where ptr is setting to root. so what am I missing? Actually you have make a good point about the class thing. i feel like I am mixing with c and c++ together lol. Thanks taxman

Comment: "`ptr` should inherit everything of `root`" is a false assumption. It's a pointer, not a reference. It "inherits" absolutely nothing but the value of `root` at the moment of assignment.

Comment: For an example of how C++ solves this problem look at how the Standard Library is designed and how you interface with it. For example, [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). A lot of this uses templates, which means code like this isn't necessarily constrained to just one type, `int`, but anything the user wants.

Comment: yes I mean the ptr = root is pointing what ever root is pointing. so I should have all the properties or something. so im not quite get it why resetting root = ptr will work...

Comment: @JeffreyStewart `ptr=root` sets `ptr` to the value of `root`, but *it's not the same object*. Later you set `ptr` to `newNode`, which changes the value of `ptr`, but not of `root`, because *they're not the same object*. Does that help explain it?

Answer (score 1):

The quick and ugly fix is to properly manipulate the `root` pointer reference:

```cpp
void in(Node* &root, const int x){
  Node* ptr = root; // Makes an independent copy of the current value of root

  // ... Existing code

  // Manipulate the caller's variable supplied as root via reference
  root = ptr;
}
```

If you step through this code in a debugger you can see that the `main()` variable `root` *does not change* inside of `in()` in that form. You're working with another version of it, `ptr`, which is not a reference, it's an independent variable.

Comment: Perhaps he wanted `Node * & ptr = root;` and forgot the ampersand. Little things like that happen a lot in C / C++.

Comment: @JohnPerry I'd argue you absolutely do not want that. If anything, just forget `ptr` and manipulate `root` instead.

Comment: You're right; I didn't think about that in the overall context of a tree; I thought of it only in the context where he seems to want to create a root on the first run.

Comment: @JohnPerry You're not wrong, I just think it's doubling down on a bad pattern. In C++ you should use either references or pointers, but mixing them together is where confusion like this sets in.

Comment: No argument from me. :-) I find it interesting that the code compiles without warning. It should not be difficult to verify statically that `root` is never modified -- at least, a lot of languages seem to detect that these days -- so at the very least a warning should be issued.

Comment: @JohnPerry Rust does a good job of brow-beating you over having things unnecessarily mutable, but C++ has a lot of catching up to do before it's that good.

Comment: I didn't have Rust in mind, since I don't use it that much. It's something I've encountered more in Ada and Kotlin, maybe somewhere else, since I can't recall where. I'd best not comment further, since StackOverflow is complaining about extended discussions, and it's past my bedtime anyway. :-)

Comment: @JohnPerry If you haven't tried Rust, it's worth giving it a go, the code checker is exceptional. Ironically it's educated me a lot on how to write better C++ code!

Answer (score 1):

Like I said before, the initialization of `ptr` *copies **the value*** of `root`. The variable `ptr` does not *reference* anything.

It's something like this:

```
+------+
| root | --\
+------+    \     +-------------+
             >--> | actual root |
+------+    /     +-------------+
| ptr  | --/
+------+
```

You have two different variables, `root` and `ptr`, that points to the same location.

Then you do the assignment

```
ptr = newNode;
```

And now it looks like this:

```
+------+       +-------------+
| root | ----> | actual root |
+------+       +-------------+

+------+       +-------------+
| ptr  | ----> | newNode     |
+------+       +-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you find the place to insert the new node in your tree and then instead of inserting the element, you point to the new object (`ptr = newNode;`). Instead, you want setPrev to point to the new node, either by leftchild or rightchild. And you need separate code for when root is null, that's why a reference to a pointer is passed to the function.

It is a nice exercise, but in production code, use std::set or std::map.